# Inserting a bullet point results in the whole email being indented in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Any idea why, when I insert a bullet point, my entire email message gets indented?

In the first image, I've typed in a test sentence and then hit enter twice to go to the next line

Enter a new line:

[image]

Now I hit the bullet point option and the entire emails get shifted, as can be seen in the next screenshot.

Email shifted:

[image]

If I hit enter again, it does not insert additonal bullet points. Instead, it maintains the indentation (which isn't my intention).

It doesn't appear to be this specific installation of Outlook 2010 as the same issue occurs on a separate machine (this OS is Win 7 and it happens on Win 10 as well). My assumption is that it's an Outlook setting that I'm missing.

Comment: Does it do the same thing if you type that up in Word?

Comment: @Mark no, Word is fine.Good question and one of the items I had checked.

Comment: @techUser I can replicate this behavior when pressing `Shift+Enter` to create new lines. It sounds like this is being sent when you press `Enter`. I would go to the Paragraph options and click `Default` to restore formatting options. Try enabling formatting symbols by pressing `Ctrl+*`. Pressing Enter should show the Paragraph symbol, not the Return symbol.

Comment: Thanks @root for pointing me in the right direction. I found out what it was and have posted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have AutoHotKey installed and am running a [script](https://sites.google.com/site/fixoutlooklinebreaks/) to prevent Outlook's line breaks when sending an email out. Thanks to @root, I realized it only after enabling the Paragraph symbol and then noticing the shift+enter functionality when entering a new line.

I'm able to use bullet points normally if I suspend the script. However, my emails appearing as normal in a recipient's mailbox (without the line breaks) is more important than using bullet points. As a result, I've left the script enabled, but at least I know what the root cause is!

Answer (score 2):

I would like to answer this because I had a similar problem, but I have no scripts running. I am an otherwise regular user.

The accepted answer did heavily guide and inspire this answer.

### I had the same problem:

I would attempt to indent one line of text, and whole swathes of text would go with it. I created an example below:

[image: Example of my problem]

### Solution:

Thankfully I was able to discover the interface show below, which contains the "Show/Hide Paragraph" option.

[image: Show/Hide Paragraph option]

Once enabled, I was able to immediately see the cause of my problem, and could infer my solution from the accepted answer: Replace new lines with paragraphs.

[image: new line versus paragraph, corrected]

### Root Cause:

Modern solutions cause modern problems - Due to other chat programs (work and home) I have become used to adding new lines via `Shift + Enter` instead of paragraph marks using only `Enter`. The error occured due to (understandable) user error since Word/Outlook are one of the few programs left that I use that *don't* send on `Enter`.

#### Caution/Pro-Tip:

`Ctrl + Enter` does send in Outlook. I discovered this when I wanted to cut-paste, then press enter multiple times. `Ctrl+V` , `Enter` easily became `Ctrl+V`, `Ctrl+Enter` when I did not release the `Ctrl` key fast enough.

Makes for an awkward half-email.